# how to restore mount points

Tags: adb, file-system, mount

i have a bricked device , after 20 hours of flashing and searching , i found that my device lost some mount points 
here is the the mount points of my device

[image]
and here is the mount points of a working device (the same)
[image]

as you can see a lot of mount points are messing:

- mmcblk0p5 (system)
- mmcblk0p7 (data)
- mmcblk0p8 (internal sdcard)
- mmcblk0p6 (cache)

this is why my device is bricked, i cannot format/mount any of those partitions , and my device is stuck on logo , my friend own the device which is working fine , so how can i extract those from his devices and push them to mine
via **adb pull and push commands** ? or is there any way to restore my mount points

**Note :** my device is Mediatek mt6589t

thank you very much